# Reading PDF from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, pdf, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, pypdf

I currently have a bucket in Google Cloud Storage with .pdf files, and I want to split each .pdf file into a multiple one-page .pdf files.

I can only load the files as BLOB's (<class 'google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob'>), and I can't find a good answer on how to read as a PdfFileReader object.

Answer (score 1):

Upon "fetching" the object/file from the bucket, you can "keep" it in the cloud function memory as a string (of bytes) or save it into a temp "directory" (`/tmp`) local to your cloud function (the memory fo that temp directory is allocated form the total memory available for the cloud function). After that, you may be able to process the data either as a string, or as a file. When you finish with processing, you probably would like to upload those files into some other storage bucket.